# Intersecting the unit n-cube and (n-1)-planes

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

(*Is this a known problem?*)

---

**Question**   Let $\ 1<n\in\mathbb N.\ $ What is the greatest $(n-1)$-area
$\ S(n)\ $ of $\ L\cap I^n\ $ where $\ I^n\subseteq\mathbb R^n\ $ is the unit cube, and $\ L\ $ runs over all possible affine $(n-1)$-hyperplanes?

My **conjecture** is that $\,\ S(n) = \sqrt{2}\quad $ (hence, $\ S(n)\ $ is constant, it does not depends on $\ n).$

Of course, $\ S(2)=\sqrt{2}\ $ indeed.

---

For instance, for $\ I^3\ :=\ [-\frac12;\frac12]^3\ $ and for
$$ T\ :=\ \{(x\ y\ z)\in\mathbb R^3:\ x+y+z = 0\} $$
the 2-area of the intersection $\ T\cap I^3\ $ is $\,\ \frac{3\cdot\sqrt3}4 < \sqrt2.$

Comment: The above smallest value is attained due to the respective compactness.

Comment: I guess you want maximal area, not minimal. Then it is indeed $\sqrt{2}$, it is a result of Keith Ball (K. M. Ball. Cube slicing in $\mathbb{R} ^n$. Proc Amer Math Soc 97:3 (1986), pp. 465-473)

Comment: Thank you, Fedor -- yes, indeed, I meant "the greatest". (My poor brainy malfunctions; I was thinking about the other, more advanced problem that involves both min and max hence I've messed up). I'll correct this in a moment.